# How to block an airport device from connecting?

Tags: macos, mac, airplay

So I have recently been noticing my neighbor's Apple TV has been showing up under my list of audio output options under "preferences."  I wanted to see if there was a way to remove it from from the menu.  I have a mac with Yosemite 10.10.1.  I don't really have any need for airplay, just need to be able to use wif.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is showing up is that you're on the same network. If this is meant to be a shared network, I'm afraid there's nothing you can do about this, however if it is not supposed to be a shared network, your neighbor probably has your wifi password and you need to change it in your router's settings. The process for doing so varies from router to router, so you should look up these directions yourself.